# VS can't find Thumb

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and 2 PictureBoxes inside. One is the background and is static(I don't move and resize it in runtime). I want the 2nd PictureBox to change its size when I drag the corner of it. So I found that Thumb can help me in this problem. You can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). But when I typed `Thumb thumb;` in code the VS said to me the next [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx). I don't understand where is the problem and what i do wrong. Please, explain me how to use Thumb in my application or how to resize the pictureBox in runtime in other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's only available in WPF projects.

**Edit :**
As for resizing the control at runtime, check this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308987/resizing-controls-at-runtime)

Comment: There is a Winforms tag at the question, so that won't help him.

Comment: @Fischermaen That's my point, he can't use the `Thumb` in a winforms project.

Comment: what can i use in my project to resize the control?

Comment: @VasiliiRuzov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308987/resizing-controls-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

There is a using missing in your code. Add `using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;` to the using section of that code file.

Comment: This is available in `PresentationFramework.dll` which is for WPF projects. See the [Inheritance Hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)